# Type mismatch when using iterators

Tags: scala

I'm getting this error when i run the below code -
type mismatch, found : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] required: Range

Where I'm going wrong ?

Functions -

```
def calcRange(i: Int, r: List[Range]):List[Range] = r match {
   case List() => List(new Range(i,i+1,1))

   case r1::rs =>
        if (r1.start-1==i) {new Range(i,r1.end,1):: rs; }

        else if(r1.end==i){new Range(r1.start,r1.end+1,1)::rs}

        else {r1::calcRange(i,rs)}
}

def recurseForRanges(l: Iterator[Int]):List[Range] = {
   var ans=List[Range]()
   while(l.hasNext){
       val cur=l.next;
       ans=calcRange(cur,ans)
    }
   ans
}

def rangify(l: Iterator[Int]):Iterator[Range] = recurseForRanges(l).toIterator
```

Driver code

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val x=rangify( List(1,2,3,6,7,8).toIterator ).reduce( (x,y) => x ++ y)      
/** This line gives the error -type mismatch, 
found : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] required: Range */
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check docs:

```
++[B](that: GenTraversableOnce[B]): IndexedSeq[B]
```

`++` returns `IndexedSeq`, not another `Range`, `Range` cannot have "holes" in them.

One way to fix it is to change `Ranges` to `IndexedSeqs` before reducing. This upcasts the `Range` so that `reduce` could take function

```
(IndexedSeq[Int], IndexedSeq[Int]) => IndexedSeq[Int]
```

because now it takes

```
(Range, Range) => Range
```

But `++` actually returns `IndexedSeq[Int]` instead of `Range` hence the type error.

```
val x = rangify(List(1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8).iterator).map(_.toIndexedSeq).reduce(_ ++ _)
```

You can as well do this kind of cast by annotating type:

```
val it: Iterator[IndexedSeq[Int]] = rangify(List(1,2,3,6,7,8).iterator)
val x = it.reduce(_ ++ _)
```

Note that your code can be simplified, without `vars`

```
def calcRange(r: List[Range], i: Int): List[Range] = r match {
   case Nil =>
      Range(i, i + 1) :: Nil
   case r1 :: rs =>
      if (r1.start - 1 == i)
        Range(i, r1.end) :: rs
      else if (r1.end == i) 
        Range(r1.start, r1.end + 1) :: rs
      else 
        r1 :: calcRange(rs, i)
}

def recurseForRanges(l: Iterator[Int]): List[Range] = {
   l.foldLeft(List.empty[Range])(calcRange)
}

def rangify(l: Iterator[Int]): Iterator[Range] = recurseForRanges(l).iterator

val x = rangify(List(1,2,3,6,7,8).iterator).map(_.toIndexedSeq).reduce(_ ++ _)
```

To explain what I've done with it:

`Range` has a factory method, you don't need `new` keyword, you don't need to specify `by` value because `1` is default.
You need no semicolons as well.

What you are doing in `recurseForRanges` is basically what `foldLeft` does, I just swapped arguments in `calcRange` it could be passed directly to `foldLeft`.

Comment: Better use `toSeq` instead of `toVector`, since it is a no-op (it returns the range itself). You can avoid `map` completely by giving a suitable type to the iterator: `val it: Iterator[IndexedSeq[Int]] = rangify(List(1,2,3,6,7,8).iterator); val x = it.reduce(_ ++ _)`.

Comment: It is not better to use `toSeq` as it doesn't work for the very reason you gave (it stays a `Range` which causes a problem). About the other thing, I will add it to the answer.

Comment: The problem is that you have `Iterator[Range]`, so for `reduce` you need `(_: Range) ++ (_: Range)` to return a `Range`, which it doesn't. After `map(_.toSeq)`, you have `Iterator[Seq[Int]]`, and `(_: Seq[Int]) ++ (_: Seq[Int])` returns a `Seq[Int]`, so everything typechecks. (Oops, just checked and `toSeq` is specialized to return a `Range`. `toIndexedSeq`, then, which has the desired type).

Comment: That is right now, after the edit. I tried to do `toSeq` myself before posting answer but it failed, I didn't think about `toIndexedSeq` though. Thanks.